# How to get specific ID users from Nav Links with Vue Js 3 and Axios

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, hyperlink

i cant find navlinks for detail page users, here's my router links and script. i use Single Page Aplication

```
              <div v-for="user in users" :key="user.id">
                <ul
                  class="py-2 text-sm text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-200"
                  aria-labelledby="dropdownAvatarNameButton"
                >
                  <li>
                    <router-link
                      :to="`/profile/${user.id}`"
                      class="block px-4 py-2 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white"
                    >
                      View Profile
                    </router-link>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
```

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
  name: 'NavbarSection',
  data() {
    return {
      users: [],
      authenticated: false,
      id: this.$route.params.id
    }
  },
  computed: {
    isAuthenticated() {
      return !!localStorage.getItem('token')
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.fetchData()
  },
  methods: {
    fetchData() {
      axios
        .get(`http://localhost:8080/users/${this.id}`)
        .then((response) => {
          this.users = response.data
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error)
        })
    },
    getUsers(userData) {
      for (let key in userData) {
        this.users.push({ ...userData[key], id: key })
      }
    },
    signOut() {
      localStorage.removeItem('token')
      localStorage.removeItem('user')
      this.authenticated = false
      this.users = {}
      window.location.reload('/')
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

i try change  :to="`/profile/${user.id}`" to :to="{ name: 'profile', params: { id: user.id }}" and change axios get method to another ways for get ( this.$route.params.id )

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.